# How to call a button from another button in another class?

Tags: java, android, function, button, methods

I have a button in my MainActivity I wanna call it in my SecondActivity inside another button basically both button does the same thing

**MainActivity**

```
 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawable myDrawable = scannedImageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myDrawable).getBitmap();
            try{
                File file = new File(MainActivity.this.getExternalCacheDir(), "myImage.png");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                file.setReadable(true, false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                intent.setType("image/png");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image Via"));
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

**SecondActivity**

```
 share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //Calling button from MainActivity
        }
    });
```

Comment: Separate your view (activity/fragments) and your business logic.

Comment: Im gonna need more details

Comment: you can make the MainActivity share button static public property and call it in the secondActivity like this MainActivity.share.performClick(), but this approach is not recommended and I believe it won't work overall as this both activities will be in the backstack

Comment: Read about different design patterns and architectures like MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc. they are all about separating your view from your business logic.

Comment: @mhemdan making the button static will not help, unless you add the button to your layout in your java code. Also it's an incredibly bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a static method in a utils class for exemple that return a OnClickListener

```
public static View.OnClickListener getShareButtonClickListener(Activity activity) {
    return new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawable myDrawable = scannedImageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)myDrawable).getBitmap();
            try{
                File file = new File(activity, "myImage.png");
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                file.setReadable(true, false);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
                intent.setType("image/png");
                activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image Via"));
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(activity, "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

and in both activities

```
share.setOnCLickListener(MyUtilsClass.getShareButtonClickListener(this))
```

**but i agree with @Abbas it's better to separate your view (activity/fragments) and your business logic**

Comment: sorry @IshakBenaissa but if you not give me more infos about your crash i cannot help you ...

Comment: I wouldn't even know how, my method I used up works fine but when I tried to replicate yours it crash